# Kubeflow parallel for loop is ignoring `parallelism` parameter

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

There is not good documentation for `dsl.ParallelFor` but I assume the `parallelism` param means - how many pods can be opened in parallel.
However, when I look at the DAG visualization, it seems like it opens all the for loop list of tasks, resulting in out of quota resources.

> This step is in Pending state with this message: pods "pipeline-pdtbc-2302481418" is forbidden: exceeded quota: kf-resource-quota, requested: cpu=1500m, used: cpu=35100m, limited: cpu=36

Since my parallelism is set to 1, it should not have asked so much CPU, rather than running one by one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set parallelism at pipeline level as well.
e.g.:    `dsl.get_pipeline_conf().set_parallelism(10)`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it is a bug in Kubeflow: see https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/6588.

Here is a hack fix:

```
def fix_parallelism(source_pipeline_path, parallelism = 10, target_pipeline_path = None):
    """
    limits the number of parallel tasks
    Args:
        source_pipeline_file(str) - path to the source pipeline yaml to be edited.
        parallelism(int) - parallelisim to use
        target_pipeline_path (str) - target path, default same as source.
    
    Returns:
        None - edits the source file.
    """
    # see https://github.com/kubeflow/pipelines/issues/6588

    with open(source_pipeline_path,'rt') as f:
        data = yaml.load(f, Loader=SafeLoader)
    pipeline_name = json.loads(data['metadata']['annotations']['pipelines.kubeflow.org/pipeline_spec'])['name']
    pipeline_index = [i for i, t in enumerate(data['spec']['templates']) if t['name']==pipeline_name][0]
    data['spec']['templates'][pipeline_index]['parallelism']=parallelism
    target_pipeline_path = target_pipeline_path or source_pipeline_path
    with open(target_pipeline_path,'wt') as f:
        yaml.dump(data, f)
```